# ASP.NET events not firing in <div> Tag

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css, visual-studio-2010

I have a  tags that when you hover over another div tag containing the login and password form appears. But for some reasons the event is not firing. 
I put the same control outside of the hover  and it can be fired.

At first i thought it was because of a drag-and-drop problem because my div could be dragged and placed in the textbox for the website link so i disabled drag-and-drop on my page but the problem doesn't go away.

The mouse cursor changes to the human finger cursor too when I hover over the div.

Here is the code on masterpage where nav-item is the cause:

```
                <div class="brick1" style="width: 33%">
                    <a href="" class="nav-item">
                        <div class="nav-hover">
                            <div class="loginbrick">
                                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="LoginPlaceHolder" runat="server">
                                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <i class="li_bulb"></i><span>Welcome, Hover over to login</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
```

Default.aspx's contentplaceholder:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="LoginPlaceHolder" runat="Server">
    <form id="AnonymousForm" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="UserName: " CssClass="aspTextView">        </asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="tbUserName" runat="server" CssClass="aspTextBox" OnTextChanged="tbUserName_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Password: " CssClass="aspTextView"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="tb_Password" runat="server" CssClass="aspTextBox"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
</form>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are enclosing div.nav-hover and div.loginbrick in a hyperlink. Try what happens when you remove that.

Comment: omg, i feel so dumb, only after you said hyperlink did i switch my <a> to <div> and it works.

Answer (score 1):

in your html brow > brick1 in which your login form is placed.

On brick1 click all event are prevented..

So try to put your form out side brick1.

I am sure your button event is not fire bCoz of js

Comment: anyway to bypass the js problem instead of putting it outside?

Comment: Where do you see JS preventing that?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout you have not added multiple form tag actually we have same problem. and i found issue was because of multiple form in same page.